# How to upload an image to Azure Bucket without using a subdomain (like in AWS S3)

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

Currently, we host this file on AWS using S3:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/apretaste/mirrors

We would like to move gigs of files to Azure, where we have all our servers, but since we are an anti-censorship tool, having the name of the project "apretaste" (or any other string) as a subdomain  will make it an easy target.

On Azure, I can only host the file as:

https://apretaste.blob.core.windows.net/mirrors

As you can see, the subdomain "apretaste" is fully exposed in Azure, while in AWS is hidden, encrypted as part of the https request.

Is there a way to hide the name in Azure? I could have not find one. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to hide the name encrypted as part of the https request in Azure?

AFAIK, there is no direct way to hide or encrypt the storage account name in Azure.

Alternatively for workaround you can use the Azure CDN (Content Delivery Network <`https://name.azureedge.net`>) endpoints hostname to connect the origin hostname<`https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net`>

You can create the Azure CDN through portal:

*Portal -> Storage account -> Azure CDN -> create endpoints.*

[image]

I tried with postman to upload file to azure blob storage using CDN endpoints it uploaded successfully.

**URL:**

`https://name.azureedge.net/<containername>/<filename> + sas token`

**Postman:**
[image]

You can refer this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-overview) for more in detail of Azure CDN.

You can also use another method in that you can configure custom domain and map it to the Azure blob storage account. Once the custom domain has been linked to your blob service endpoint it shows name of the organization since the displayed custom domain effectively encrypts the storage account name. To know more in detail kindly refer the below document.

- [Map a custom domain to an Azure Blob Storage endpoint - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal)